# How to make bean injection in spring boot mvc web application

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Can you please tell where and how i have to write:

```
final ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
final HelloController store = context.getBean("store", HelloController .class);
```

so that dependency injection takes place and my objects are created when the application starts. And i could get the total price of created objects.

HelloController.java

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    private List<Products> storeList  = new ArrayList<Products>();
    private int            totalPrice = 0;

    public List<Products> getStoreList() {
        return this.storeList;
    }

    public int getTotalPrice() {
        return this.totalPrice;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @PostMapping("/totalprice")
    public String countTotalPrice(@RequestParam("name") final String name, final Model model) {

        final String[] values = name.trim().split("\\s*,\\s*");

        final List<Integer> listIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            listIds.add(Integer.parseInt(values[i]));
            for (int j = 0; j < this.storeList.size(); j++) {
                if (listIds.get(i) == this.storeList.get(j).getId()) {
                    this.totalPrice += this.storeList.get(j).getPrice();
                }
            }
        }
        model.addAttribute("name", this.totalPrice);
        return "totalprice";
    }

    public void setStoreList(final List<Products> storeList) {
        this.storeList = storeList;
    }

}
```

MainApp.java - Run the Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApp {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args);

    }
}
```

Products.java - my class for products

```
public class Products {
    private String name;
    private int    price;
    private int    id;

    public Products(final String name, final int price, final int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.id = id;
    }
    ...
```

My beans.xml file

```
<beans 

  ... 
  <bean id="product1"
    class="... .Products">
    <constructor-arg name="name" value="Cherry" />
    <constructor-arg name="price" value="500" />
    <constructor-arg name="id" value="1" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="product2"
    class="... .Products">
    <constructor-arg name="name" value="Cucumber" />
    <constructor-arg name="price" value="1000" />
    <constructor-arg name="id" value="2" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="product3"
    class="... .Products">
    <constructor-arg name="name" value="Apple" />
    <constructor-arg name="price" value="3000" />
    <constructor-arg name="id" value="3" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="store"
          class="... .controller.HelloController">
        <property name="storeList">
            <list>
                <ref bean="product1"/>
                <ref bean="product2"/>
                <ref bean="product3"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath*:beans.xml"})
public class Config {
}
```

And use your beans from xml like:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @Autowired
    Store store;
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! But now i'm getting the following error: "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'store' method 
public java.lang.String by.iba.gomel.ustarastsenka.controller.HelloController.index()
to {[/]}: There is already 'helloController' bean method" I added my beans.xml file above

Comment: You changed your code. Now: 
1) remove bean with class="... .controller.HelloController" from xml
2) create bean with type List with <util:list id="storeList" value-type="... .Product">
        <ref bean="product1" />
        <ref bean="product2" />
        <ref bean="product3" />
    </util:list> 
3) Inject list into controller @Autowired List<Product> storeList;

Answer (score 1):

```
@ImportResource("classpath:beans.xml")
```

Add this annotation next to the SpringBootApplication annotation.

Then, where u need reference to the 'store' bean, just say

```
@Autowired
Store store;
```